# What migration paths should we allow?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

See this [blog post from Jeff](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/). I suggest we need to allow migration to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (the programming questions) and [math.stackexchange](http://math.statckexchange.com) (the more mathematical questions). What other migration paths do we need?

Comment: Can this cover sites like MathOverflow, Or-Exchange and BioStar?  Or are those independent entities?

Comment: @ars. We won't be able to migrate questions from or to Q&A sites that aren't part of the stackexchange network.

Comment: Great; I think SO and math are our primary targets at this point.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I have now enabled:

- math --> stats
- stats --> math
- stats --> stack overflow

As Srikant noted in his comment, we want migration paths to be based on "happens in the wild frequently", not "could theoretically happen at some unknown possible point in the future"..

Comment: Thanks.........

Answer (score 5):

We also need the reverse paths I guess (i.e., SO --> Stats, Math --> Stats). I do not think we need anything else.

Answer (score 4):

I participate in the GIS stackexchange community. There may be enough cross over in the future warrant this, but currently their is little need.

The vast majority of questions are related to programming aspects of GIS software.

Comment: This isn't a bad idea, although I expect that most of the flow would be from GIS to Stats (unfortunately!)

Comment: Agreed, the only example I think that would maybe come up here that people on the GIS community could help with would be how to handle big geo data questions.

Comment: A candidate for stats => GIS migration has just come up: 
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6463/what-software-is-used-for-maps-of-the-us-or-other-arbitrary-areas

Comment: A visual review of the migration record shows one migration to and one migration from GIS during the lifetimes of both sites (almost two years now). I guess people are pretty good at figuring where to post their questions :-).

Comment: Only two! I guess perhaps this was just wishful thinking on my part that the communities would overlap.

Answer (score 4):

[Computation Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)?   There's certainly some overlap of subject matter with CrossValidated. It's still in beta, and [needs more questions if it's ever to get past beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28815/computational-science). I'm not clear if migration to/from beta sites is allowed.

Comment: Yes, we can migrate questions to any sites, including beta sites. (Or see [Is it possible to migrate questions to a beta SE site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136687/150510))

Comment: SO and math have been handy targets indeed. To date--after moderating for 15 months--I recall seeing exactly *one* close vote given by the community for a message that needed to be migrated anywhere else, so additional options currently have little use. A method that works well is to vote to close and make a suggestion in a comment to the original question concerning a good migration destination. You can also flag the question and make a recommendation.  (I have sent a bunch of questions to CogSci through that mechanism thanks to flags by an attentive member of both sites.)

Answer (score 2):

Certainly physics.SE at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Looking further ahead, we should consider adding [Quantitative Finance](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117/quantitative-finance) if and when it comes out of beta (currently still in the 'commit' phase).

Answer (score 1):

To tex.SE? A lot less common than math.SE or StackOverflow, but seems worth considering to me. Example: [Typographic conventions for width of figures in LaTeX data analysis reports](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4501/449) Reverse path probably not needed.

Comment: I think we should only request migration paths for questions require *frequent* migration to another site. I suspect that migrating questions to tex.SE will be a lot less than to some of the other targets such as math.SE.

Answer (score -2):

Didn't find this discussion anywhere else in meta, so I'd like to add that we should allow migration to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: There are a strictly limited number of migration paths we can have, & migrations to [datascience.SE] would be *much* less common than the paths we have.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that we can't have a 4th one