# Quant.SE is no longer in Beta. Can we add it as a migration target?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, migration

Occasionally we get questions with no statistical content, such as

- [Return on bonds and stocks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425659/return-on-bonds-and-stocks)

So our choices are to either close as off-topic or migrate. But right now, only a mod could migrate this question because Quant.SE isn't a migration target in the VTC dialogue.

Quant.SE is no longer in Beta, which means it is feasible to add the website as a migration target to the VTC dialogue.

Should we add it as a migration target? Is this a good idea?

Comment: We are limited in the number of targets.  If I remember correctly, we get at most three.  That implies Quant.SE should be a *more frequent* target than the current ones (CV Meta, Math.SE, and SO).  That seems unlikely based on the history of posts on CV.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize we were limited in the number of targets. In that case, it makes sense that Meta, Math and SO would be the three we should pick.

Comment: See the original thread upon which the choice of the two current ones (besides meta) was based: [What migration paths should we allow?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/505/what-migration-paths-should-we-allow) ... the answer from Jeff Atwood being the conclusion of the discussion

Comment: See also this somewhat related thread [Would it make sense to add Data Science SE to the list of suggested sites for migration of a question?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4929/would-it-make-sense-to-add-data-science-se-to-the-list-of-suggested-sites-for-mi)

Comment: It isn't clear to me why we should have that constraint, though. On [SO] there are >3 migration targets.

Comment: I never heard of Quant.SE till now, please edit a link into the top of your question: https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11):

I didn't know this, but we are limited to only 3 migration targets. It makes the most sense to allocate these 3 slots to the 3 most prevalent targets, which I assume are

- Meta.Stats.SE,
- Math.SE and
- SO.SE.

Comment: Seems like that limit ought to increase as the number of sites on the StackExchange network increases.  I mean, if a limit of 3 sites was once appropriate when there were fewer potential migration targets, then presumably a limit of more than 3 would be appropriate now that there are more  potential migration targets.

Comment: This would be an appropriate point to raise on the SO-wide Meta. I think 3 is just a default setting, chosen for no especially rigorous reason. What I've learned in the past from interactions with the SO staff and moderators is that they're reluctant to deviate from the default configurations on most websites (SE.SO being a "special case" due to its extraordinary volume of traffic).